# Как правильно составить mysql запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно получить `id` из таблицы `fnews`, где `userid = $_post['userid']` и `newsid = $_post['newsid']`, при этом получить ещё `userid` из таблицы `news` где `id = $_post['newsid']`

Как можно сделать это одним запросом?

Comment: Почитайте про join-ы

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать нечто типа:

```
SELECT fnews.id, news.userid 
FROM fnews 
WHERE fnews.userid = $_POST['userid'] AND fnews.newsid = $_POST['newsid'] 
INNER JOIN news on fnews.newsid = news.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то мудрено все у вас, не понятно в чем разница данных в таблицах fnews и news. Можно поступить проще, выполнить денормализацию данных и все хранить в одной таблице. На практике этот способ применяется часто, он позволяет делать наиболее простые и быстрые запросы. Если данные свести в одной таблице нельзя, то используйте JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT 'fnews' source, id 
  FROM fnews
  WHERE userid = $_post['userid'] AND newsid = $_post['newsid']
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'news', userid 
  FROM news 
  WHERE id = $_post['newsid']
```